# Resolve DNS for a docker container with dnsmasq

Tags: docker, dnsmasq

I have a *dnsmasq* service that is currently bound to *127.0.0.1* pointing to my minikube instance like so:

```
address=/.k8s.local/192.168.39.184
```

I'd like to run docker containers that will communicate with the minikube instance using the DNS I specified.
When I set the container's DNS using `docker run --dns 127.0.0.1 ...` docker outputs the following message: `WARNING: Localhost DNS setting (--dns=127.0.0.1) may fail in containers.`
If I use the the host's network like so `docker run --net host --dns 127.0.0.1 ...` everything works as expected.
How do I configure the docker bridge to also resolve DNS using my local dnsmasq service?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the host's local DNS resolver (e.g. `dnsmasq`) from your Docker containers if they are on a [**user defined network**](https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/issues/1654). In that case a container's `/etc/resolv.conf` will have the nameserver `127.0.0.11` (a.k.a. the Docker's [embedded DNS server](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services)), which can forward DNS requests to the host's loopback address properly.

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.1
$ docker run --rm alpine cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
$ docker network create demo
557079c79ddf6be7d6def935fa0c1c3c8290a0db4649c4679b84f6363e3dd9a0
$ docker run --rm --net demo alpine cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```